# Code working on DEvC++ and Ideone but not on competetion website

Tags: c

This code works on DEVCPP and IDEONE but is not accepted by the website where this question is.
It is an on-line competition where the in built compiler is saying: COMPILATION FAILED.
This is a program which finds str2 in str1 and returns index of sub-string if found. Else prints -1.

> I know using GOTO is not recommended. :( Sorry for this. Cant figure out a way for this.
>
> IDEONE link: [LINK](http://ideone.com/wV7V8m)

Code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[19], s2[19],*p,c,d,k=0;
    int i;
    gets(s1);   gets(s2);
    p = strstr(s1,s2);

    if( (strlen(s2) > strlen(s1))   ||   !p      ) 
    {printf("-1");goto ex;}

    for(i=0;i<strlen(s1); i++)
    {
        c = s1[i];
        d = s1[i+1];
        if(c == s2[k]      &&    d == s2[k+1])
        {
            printf("%d", i);
            goto ex;

        }
    }
    ex:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could get rid of the `goto` by replacing it by `return 0;`

Comment: `I know using GOTO is not recommended`. so as `using gets`

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Thank you sir, And what about the compilation error.. Why is it coming. Any help on that?

Comment: devc++ is quite old an not maintained anymore. get some newer IDE/ompiler e.g. code::blocks

Comment: use break to get rid of that goto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.c:15:14: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

Make `i` unsigned.

```
a.c:19:9: error: array subscript has type 'char'
```

Make `k` int.

Notes:

Use `fgets` instead of `gets`.

`goto` is ok in some circumstances, like the pattern you use can be used to do some default-stuff (eg logging) before `return`. Also for dropping out from inner loops, jump-table usage (&&), doing `default:` after having done one of the `case x:`'s, retry after `case x:` and a few others.

Comment: Thank you sir... Blunders i do sometimes.. -_-